# Is there a word that contains all the vowels?

Tags: single-word-requests

"Jealousy" contains most of the vowels but lacks 'i'. Is there a word in the English language that contains every vowel (and preferably 'y')?

Comment: Is there? Unequivocally, there is.

Comment: Not perfectly fitting xkcd-comic: http://xkcd.com/853/

Comment: Oh, unquestionably.

Comment: Am I wrong thinking, that that question is a perfect fit for the site?

Comment: Relevant: http://digitalcommons.butler.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=4471&context=wordways

Comment: To future visitors, please, do not nominate `education` that answer was submitted but deleted,  someone else suggested it in an edit, but that too was rejected. Please see @FogleBird answer below and SCROLL the list; the word *educationally* has been supplied.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

I totally rule at [Clockwords](http://www.kongregate.com/games/gabob/clockwords-prelude) by using *sequoia* and *facetiously*. Wikipedia used to have a list of words containing all the vowels, but the article has since been deleted. Some of the fun facts it mentioned included:

> The word *Iouea*, a genus of sea sponges, contains all five regular vowels and no other letters. [...] There are many words that feature all five regular vowels occurring only once in alphabetical order, the most common being *abstemious* and *facetious*. [...] Considering *y* as a vowel, the suffix *-ly* can be added to a number of these words; thus the shortest word containing six unique vowels in alphabetical order is *aeriously*, with nine letters (OED)[.]

Comment: If something is like a sea sponge, is it *Ioueay*?

Comment: If y can be considered a vowel when it seems to act like one, so can w (the loan-word cwm).

Comment: @User123: yes, what about it? It is clearly not as short as *Iouea*, it clearly does not contain the vowels in alphabetical order like *facetious* does, and it is clearly missing the *y* that *aeriously* is not missing at all.

Answer (score 39):

I wrote this simple Python script to analyze the official Scrabble dictionary for words that contain each of the vowels and the letter 'y', as you requested:

```
vowels = set('aeiouy')
with open('TWL06.txt') as file:
    for line in file:
        word = line.strip().lower()
        letters = set(word)
        if vowels <= letters:
            print word
```

The result is below, sorted alphabetically (156 words).

I did the same thing, but omitted 'y'. You can see those results (1905 words) here: http://www.michaelfogleman.com/static/files/vowels.txt

```
abstemiously
actinomycetous
adventitiously
aeronautically
ambidextrously
aneuploidy
antiregulatory
audiometry
authoritatively
autoeciously
autotetraploidy
autotypies
basidiomycetous
bimolecularly
buoyancies
cleistogamously
coeducationally
coequality
coevolutionary
communicatively
conceptuality
consequentially
consuetudinary
corynebacterium
coulometrically
countercyclical
counterrallying
cyanobacterium
cytomegalovirus
daguerreotypies
daguerreotyping
daguerreotypist
delusionary
denunciatory
devolutionary
documentarily
educationally
efficaciously
elocutionary
encouragingly
equationally
equilibratory
equivocality
equivocally
eudiometrically
eugeosynclinal
eukaryotic
eulogistically
euphonically
euphorically
evolutionarily
evolutionary
exclusionary
facetiously
gelatinously
genitourinary
gesticulatory
grandiloquently
gregariously
hellaciously
heterosexuality
homosexuality
hyaluronidase
hyaluronidases
hypercautious
hyperfastidious
hyperfunctional
ichthyofaunae
immunoassayable
immunotherapy
importunately
incommensurably
inefficaciously
instantaneously
insubordinately
insurrectionary
intravenously
magniloquently
mendaciously
miscellaneously
monumentality
mouthwateringly
mycobacterium
nefariously
neurofibrillary
neurogenically
neurologically
neuropathically
neuropsychiatry
neuroradiology
neurotically
oleaginously
ostentatiously
outwearying
overmaturity
oxyuriases
paramyxoviruses
perspicaciously
pertinaciously
phenylketonuria
phenylthiourea
phenylthioureas
pneumatolytic
polybutadiene
polybutadienes
praseodymium
praseodymiums
precariously
precautionary
psychosexuality
questionably
questionary
radiolucency
renunciatory
revolutionarily
revolutionary
sacrilegiously
semidocumentary
sequaciously
simultaneously
subordinately
subventionary
subversionary
successionally
sulfinpyrazone
sulfinpyrazones
superloyalist
superloyalists
supermajority
supernormality
supersonically
tautonymies
temerariously
tenaciously
turbomachinery
uncomplimentary
uncongeniality
uncopyrightable
unemotionally
unemployability
unequivocably
unequivocally
unexceptionably
unextraordinary
uninformatively
unintentionally
unquestionably
unreasoningly
unrecognizably
unrevolutionary
ventriloquially
veraciously
vexatiously
vituperatory
volumetrically
voyeuristically
```

Comment: bash: `egrep "([aeiou].*){5,}" /usr/share/myspell/dicts/en_US.dic | grep a | grep o | grep u | grep e | grep i`

Comment: Python is much more fun.

Comment: related: `uses_all()` function from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5227524/use-function-to-return-a-list-of-words-containing-required-letters/5239674#5239674

Comment: @user unknown - That's "five vowels", not "5 different vowels" - it will match `eeeee` `:P`.

Comment: @Kobi: That's only a first filter, and it is `at least 5 vowels` - the rest is done with the 5 greps in the pipe.

Comment: @user - oops. My bad `:)`

Answer (score 16):

Is there a word that contains all vowels and the letter Y? Unquestionably.

Comment: More than one, at that!

Comment: ... (The word "Unquestionably" being an example. Twas meant to be wordplay).

Comment: What a stroke of genius! Nice.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, one such word is *precariously*.

Comment: Now that I really like.  Because you have both "precarious" (without a 'y') and "precariously."  So the words have "a, e, i, o, u, and sometimes 'y'! =D