# Words using all possible vowels

Tags: vowels, consonants

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a word that contains all the vowels?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/18085/is-there-a-word-that-contains-all-the-vowels)

Is there a word in English that contains the 5 letters that are exclusively vowels (a, e, i, o, u) as well as the 3 letters that can be used as vowels (h, w, y)?  I would be happy with a word that used the latter 3 even if in that word they were consonants.

Comment: Are there any English words that use *h* and *w* as vowels? The only words I can think of immediately are Welsh.

Comment: [Is there a word that contains all the vowels?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/18085/is-there-a-word-that-contains-all-the-vowels) Complete with a Python script and even a simple bash command line, both of which can be easily adapted to include any and all letters you wish.

Comment: 'h'? That's a new one. Are there any words, no other restrictions, that use 'h' as a vowel at all?

Comment: I wouldn't say so _authoritatively_, but I'd venture to guess you could find words with 2 of the 3 (h, w, y) letters, but not all three. Maybe you could find a website [warehousing](http://everything2.com/title/words+with+all+the+vowels) a list of candidate words, and see if any of those words fit your criteria. (Then again, check the list RegDwight provided. It's mouthwateringly delicious.)

Comment: @J.R. - :-) !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!