# Is "facetious" unique?

Tags: orthography

Is "facetious" unique, as the only English word with all vowels appearing once, and in alphabetical order? Or, if you count Y as a vowel (as some do) does the same apply to "facetiously"?

Comment: This topic has also been covered [here](http://oxforddictionaries.com/words/what-word-contains-the-five-vowels-a-e-i-o-u-in-the-right-order).

Comment: Kind of a trivia question - not sure if welcome here

Answer (score 1):

Per RegDwighт♦'s [answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/18088/11433) to the question mentioned as a possible duplicate, *[abstemious](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/abstemious#Adjective)* also has all the vowels in order.

Both *[facetiously](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/facetiously#Adverb)* and *[abstemiously](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/abstemiously#Adverb)* have the five usual vowels and also Y, with the vowels and Y appearing in alphabetical order.

*Note:* I'm uncertain whether the present question is a duplicate, so haven't voted to close it on that account.  Even if it isn't a duplicate, it might be considered off topic, like the previous question.