# a word that contains every vowel contigiously

Tags: vowels

I want a word that contains every vowel `aeiou` in a **CONTIGUOUS** fashion.

Bonus points if it ends with `y`. ;)

Comment: I want the vowels to be CONTIGUOUS

Comment: [IOUEA](http://digitalcommons.butler.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=3771&context=wordways) is contiguous. The linked article also lists AIOUEA and OIOUEAE. There don't seem to be any with Y.

Comment: Did you read the article pointed to by @Josh61? The word is Iouea, a genus of sea sponges, and it seems to be the only one.

Comment: [All the English vowels](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/modestproposal.pdf) in one word? Impossible. There are thirteen of them, at least, and more in other dialects. The link points to American English pronunciation, as in [Kenyon & Knott](https://archive.org/stream/pronouncingdicti00unse?ui=embed#page/n6/mode/1up).

Answer (score 6):

[Miaoued](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/miaoued)

(dictionary.com)

> verb (used without object)
>
> 3.
>   to make the sound of a cat.
>
> 4.
>   to make a spiteful or catty remark.

Comment: The vowel letters in "abstemiously" are not contiguous (although they are in alphabetical order). This would be a good answer to the supposed "[duplicate](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/18085/is-there-a-word-that-contains-all-the-vowels)" (which is not really a duplicate) but it doesn't work as an answer to this question.

Comment: true, I misread the question, updated!

Comment: This seems to be the French spelling.  In English, I would only understand it spelled as *meowed* which would not satisfy the question.

Comment: Well it appears in dicitonary.com, thefreedicitonary.com, Collins dictionary, and wiktionary, all of which are reputable sources

Comment: @cobaltduck I don't know about your cat, but mine says miaou

Comment: @Matt  I suggest you add the Free Dictionary reference to the text of your answer, to avoid questions about your Felinglish.

Comment: What about Miaoued-ly ? Is that a word?